# RealVNC - SSMS - Application Menu does not work

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, realvnc

When using RealVNC Viewer for remote connection I can't use SSMS' Menu. When clicking, for example, `File`, only thing it does is highlight if. But the drop-down menu doesn't work.

Tested with other solutions and it's clear this is VNC issue - RDP works as expected, same with TeamViewer. Same computers, same session on remote machine.

Anyone knows it's a bug, feature or some setting in VNC (Client or Server)?

Machine I'm connecting from is XPS8500 with windows 10 Pro, target is Windows 7 Pro on Optiplex 3040.

EDIT: 
Versions:
Real VNC Server v 6.2.1 (r32538) x64.
Windows 7 Professional v6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 14.0.17224.0

Comment: Which version of VNC Server are you using? The About dialog will tell you the version number. Also, forgive my ignorance I am unfamiliar with "SSMS", does that stand for something?

Comment: @srk - Edited Q with relevant info.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you should try not using the Mirror Driver. From the Server's options UI go to the Troubleshooting page. Untick the option "Use mirror driver to capture screen".